# How do you adjust sliderInput values to reduce the data frame in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

This a functioning shiny app that I found on Stack Overflow

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

# Sample Data
area    <- seq(from=10,to=100, by=10);peri <- seq(from=2710.1,to=2800.1, by=10)
shape   <- seq(from=0.1,to=1, by=0.1);perm <- seq(from=1,to=100, by=10)
my_data <- as.data.frame(cbind(area,peri,shape,perm))

ui = fluidPage(
   sidebarPanel(
   sliderInput("range", "Select Range",min = 1, max = 10, value = c(2,    
   5)),width = 4),
   mainPanel(tableOutput("view"))
)

server = function(input, output) {
 output$view <- renderTable({
test <- my_data[input$range[1]:input$range[2],]
test}, include.rownames = FALSE)
}

}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

I would like to shorten the dataframe based on the numeric values of a column

I tried changing the line:

```
 mydata$area <- my_data$area[input$range[1]:input$range[2]]
```

However I realized that this reduces the rows of that column without adjusting the other rows to match the same number of rows. Any ideas on how to reduce the other rows as well?

Comment: check the `subset` function.

Comment: I figured it out, I used the filter function in dplyr, thanks